# Text to Speech Metro App - requires 3rd Party library/plugins - where are they?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, text-to-speech

Has anybody yet looked at using Text to Speech in a Windows 8 Metro app. Functionality should be fine with a desktop app, but according to MS, metro apps require a 3rd party library/plugin.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/winappswithcsharp/thread/553abb2c-19ef-41b0-b189-37b8f6b38713

I've looked, and looked and looked. Has anybody looked at this yet, or have any idea if there are currently third party libraries available or under development? If so, could you point me somewhere useful?

Bing is not useful to me - this needs to operate offline too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bing Translator. It has both TTS and ASR but you have to access it via the network.

http://www.bing.com/translator

You can also look at Project Hawaii

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/hawaii/download.aspx

This supposedly works for windows phone not sure if you can use it with windows 8

http://ttsforwindowsphone7.codeplex.com/discussions

Trying to find a non-networked solution myself but so far everything's on the cloud